# How to correctly implement subclass constructor in Objective-C

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I have a base class who's constructor sets the objects state given some external data:

```
@implementation XMlContent

     - (id)initWithParser:(NSXMLParser *)xmlParser {
        self = [super init];
        if (self) {
            if(xmlParser != nil){
            _documentFormat = @"xml";
            _xmlParser = xmlParser;
            xmlParser.delegate = self;
            } else{
                return nil;
            }
        }
        return self; }
```

I have a subclass of this object and I have overridden this constructor like so (probably wrong):

```
@implementation AtomContent
      - (id)initWithParser:(NSXMLParser *)xmlParser
    {
        self = [super init];
        if (self) {
            if(xmlParser != nil){
                self.xmlParser = xmlParser;
                self.xmlParser.delegate = self;
                self.documentFormat = @"atom";
            } else{
                return nil;
            }
        }
        return self;
    }
```

The issue I have is that when creating an instance of the subclass (AtomContent in this case) I get back an instance of the superclass and thus superclass methods are called rather than those in the subclass. Looking at my subclass constructor its obvious why. My question is how do I property implement the subclass constructor so the super class is init'd but references to 'self' are to the subclass? Should I not override the constructor but rather use setters to set object state?

**Corrections**

> I get back an instance of the superclass and thus superclass

-No. Specifically my issue is that base class implementation is used (the NSXMLParser delegate methods) rather than the subclass'. I am, indeed, returned an instance of the subclass.

> constructor

-Yeah ok.. "Initializer"

Thanks!

Comment: How are you instantiating your object? BTW, in Objective-C there are no "constructors"

Comment: Also, are you sure you want to call [super init] instead of [super initWithParser:xmlParser] inside your AtomContent class?

Comment: *"When creating an instance of the subclass I get back an instance of the superclass"* - This is wrong.

Comment: @MartinR - Well, right and wrong.  He does, in a sense, get back an instance of the superclass, wrapped by whatever additional stuff his subclass defines.

Comment: If you reference `self.xyz`, and you have not defined property xyz in your subclass, the superclass version of the property will be accessed.  (And in general it's rare that you'd need to have both subclass and superclass define the same property.)

Comment: @LuisCien ok.. "Initializers" :)

Comment: @HotLicks good point. Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're not calling the designated initializer from your subclass initializer, which causes you to need to repeat a lot of work in the subclass's `initWithXMLParser:` implementation. Here's how I'd do it:

```
// Superclass
- (id)initWithParser:(NSXMLParser *)xmlParser {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        if(xmlParser != nil) {
            _documentFormat = @"xml";
            _xmlParser = xmlParser;
            xmlParser.delegate = self;
        }
        else {
            return nil;
        }
    }

    return self; 
}

// Subclass
- (id)initWithParser:(NSXMLParser *)xmlParser
{
    self = [super initWithParser:xmlParser];
    if (self) {
        self.documentFormat = @"atom";
    }
    return self;
}
```

I should add that if you are truly getting an instance of the superclass returned, then your problem would be in allocation, not initialization, as the `isa` pointer and hence the method lookup tables are set inside `alloc` and thus are set at the time `init` is called. I would rate the chance of that being your problem in actuality as being low.

Comment: Thanks a lot. You're right this is much better. Specifically it seems that the NSXMLParser that I pass to - (id)initWithParser:(NSXMLParser *)xmlParser is using the base class as the delegate. This is not what I want. I want the subclass implementation to be used. Should I set the delegate in a setter rather than in the init method?

Comment: In Objective-C, all methods are dispatched dynamically. When any method is called by anyone, the code that is executed is the implementation 'deepest' in the inheritance hierarchy. If you assign an `AtomContent` instance as the delegate of an `NSXMLParser`, then the code executed will be what's in `AtomContent` to the extent possible. Verify the following - 1) you're not setting the parser's delegate at some later point in the code to a superclass instance. 2) You have spelled the NSXMLParserDelegate implementations correctly (including whether class or instance methods)

Comment: @Nick - You are wrong.  "self" refers to the instance being created, which if you test it's class will be your class.  If you define delegate methods that "hide" the superclass delegate methods, your methods will be invoked by the delegate user.  You are confusing yourself somehow.

Comment: @HotLicks Gotcha. My problem/confusion is why base class implementation is executed rather than that of the subclasses. I think it is a symptom of an error I have made such as Carl has eluded to. I realize that my post has some inaccuracies in it and I will clear them up shortly. Thanks

Comment: @Nick put breakpoints in the subclass's `initWith...` as well as in the subclass and superclass implementations of the `NSXMLParserDelegate` methods. In initializer note the address of `self`, `self.parser`, `self.parser.delegate`. In the delegate methods, note the addresses of `self` and the `parser` instance that's being passed as the first argument of most of those methods.

Comment: Thank you. I got it resolved. It seems that the content I was attempting to parse was utf-16. This caused the parser to return an error. Once I noticed the encoding issue and corrected it everything worked great. I think I had two issues: the first you answered in your comments, I was setting the delegate twice and the second being the encoding issue which lead me down the wrong rabbit hole. Thanks again!